# openmp - using locks for 2d array summation

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, synchronization, openmp, locks

I'm a new user to openmp, and I try to parallelize a part of my program and use locks for a 2 dimentional array. I won't go over all the details of my real problem, but instead discuss the following simplified example:

Let's say I have a huge group of N>>1 particles, which their x,y locations is stored in some data structure . I want to create a 2d counter array that will represent a grid, and count all the particles in each cell of the grid:

count[j][k]+=1  (for the corresponding j,k of each particle, according to his x,y values)

Using locks is a natural choice (The 2D array is on the scale of 100x100 and above , so when you have a 20 cores machine, the chances of 2 threads updating an array element simultaneously is still pretty low). The relevant parts of the code:

//define a 2d lock:

```
omp_lock_t **count_lock;
count_lock = new omp_lock_t* [J+1];
for(j=0;j<=J;j++) {
    count_lock[j]=new omp_lock_t[K+1];
    memset(count_lock[j],0,(K+1)*sizeof(omp_lock_t));
}
```

//initializing:

```
for(j=0;j<=J;j++) 
    for(k=0;k<=K;k++){
        omp_init_lock(&(count_lock[j][k]));
        omp_unset_lock(&(count_lock[j][k]));
    }
```

//using the lock (after determining  the right j,k):

```
omp_set_lock(&(count_lock[j][k]));
count[j][k] += 1;
omp_unset_lock(&(count_lock[j][k]));
```

//destroying the lock:

```
for(i=0;i<=J;i++) 
    for(j=0;j<=K;j++)
        omp_destroy_lock(&(count_lock[i][j]));

for (j=0; j<=J; j++)
    delete[] count_lock[j];

delete[] count_lock;
```

The particles are divided into groups of 500 particles. each group is a linked list of particles, and all the particle groups are also forming a linked list. The paralellization comes from parallelizing the "for" loop that goes over the particle groups.

For some reason I can't seem to get it right...no improvement in performance is obtained, and the simulation get stuck after a few iterations.

I tried using "atomic" but it gave even worse performance than the serial code. Another option I tried is to create a private 2D array for each thread, and then sum them up. I got some improvement that way, but it is pretty costly and I hope there is a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: *Let's say I have a huge group of N>>1 particles, which their x,y locations is stored in some data structure .*  No, let's have you tell us what data structure you have stored the particles in.  That has a very material impact on feasible solutions to your problem.  Locks, especially such fine-grained ones as you are trying to implement, are a canonical way of serialising parallel code and exceedingly harmful to performance.

Comment: The particles are divided into groups of 500 particles. each group is a linked list of particles, and all the particle groups are also forming a linked list. The paralellization comes from parallelizing the "for" loop that goes over the particle groups

Comment: This is one of those situations where the answer to your question is *Well, I wouldn't start from there*.  You could try using OpenMP's `atomic` directive to guard updates to the counters in the 2D array.  This will probably operate better (and will be easier to get to work) than all the locks you are having trouble with.  But it is only likely to show a marked improvement over the lock version if the likelihood of two threads wanting to update the same grid cell simultaneously is low.  If the likelihood is high then `atomics` will serialise the code just as the locks do.  You write that ...

Comment: ... *Using locks is a natural choice* but I'm not sure that is ever true with OpenMP; for parallel computing lock-free algorithms and data structures are a much more natural choice.  Which leads to my final comment ... a good answer to your question depends on the details of your real problem which you have not shared with us.  And which leaves us sitting on one side offering 'helpful' comments.

Comment: The 2D array is on the scale of 100x100 and above , so when you have a 20 cores machine, the chances of 2 threads updating an array element is still pretty low. I tried using atomic but it gave even worse performance than the serial code. Sorry if I missed any important info when describing the problem...I didn't want to burden anyone with unnecessary information

Comment: Another option is to create a private array for each thread, and then sum them up. I got some improvement that way, but it is pretty costly and I hope there is a better way.